# How to detect uninstall of an application in a recycleview?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, uninstallation

I'm trying to make an app uninstaller like Easy Uninstaller,  I used recyclerview to list all the apps installed on the system. When the user clicks on the application an alert pops up asking "are you sure to uninstall the application?" if clicked on uninstall the app doesn't go away from the recyclerview. I want to remove the app from the recyclerview list when the app is uninstalled.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position){

        ApkInfoExtractor apkInfoExtractor = new ApkInfoExtractor(context1);

        final String ApplicationPackageName = (String) stringList.get(position);

        double ApplicationSize= apkInfoExtractor.GetAppSize(ApplicationPackageName);

        final String ApplicationLabelName = apkInfoExtractor.GetAppName(ApplicationPackageName);
        Drawable drawable = apkInfoExtractor.getAppIconByPackageName(ApplicationPackageName);

        viewHolder.textView_App_Name.setText(ApplicationLabelName);

        viewHolder.textView_App_Package_Name.setText(String.format("%.2f MB", ApplicationSize));

        viewHolder.imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        viewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:"+ApplicationPackageName));
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context1.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
```

I tried using this code:

```
        PackageManager pm = context1.getPackageManager();
        boolean isInstalled = isPackageInstalled(ApplicationPackageName, pm);
        if(!isInstalled){
            int index = position;
            stringList.remove(index);
            notifyItemRemoved(index);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(index, getItemCount());
        }

    private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packageName, PackageManager packageManager) {
        try {
            packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
            return true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The above code only removes the app from the list onClick it does that before uninstalling the application, The task is cancelled it still removes it from the list.

Comment: Register a listener for [the `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` broadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Intent#action_package_removed) and update your data model at that point.

Comment: I tried adding a broadcast receiver class but it wasn't detecting the change inside the activity.

Comment: If you register the receiver using `registerReceiver()` in the activity, using an anonymous inner class of `BroadcastReceiver` or something, your activity should be able to find out about the broadcast.

Comment: I wrote the above code inside an sepearte java class  file and inside the main activity only code is there for adding recycleview. Where should I add the broadcast receiver? Could you please elaborate.

Comment: "Where should I add the broadcast receiver?" --  I cannot really answer that. You indicated that you wanted to find out the uninstall event in an activity. So, perhaps in `onCreate()` of the activity, you call `registerReceiver()`, then call `unregisterReceiver()` in `onDestroy()` of that activity.